How to Use C# Class as a Unity Gameobject?
I feel like I am missing a very fundamental concept of OOP and was hoping somebody could explain it to me.
I started my game with 1 basic enemy type that is spawned in with an Enemy Prefab in Unity and the mobSpawner script. I would like to make more enemies that all derive from a single enemy class.
Initially I had the spawnRate and spawnTimer variables declared inside of the MobSpawner script. But when I tried to move that into a separate script I was no longer able to assign the Mobs in Unity as they were not game objects.
public class mobSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{

    //declare mob and mob2 classes
    public MobScript mob1 = new Mob1();
    public Mob2Script mob2 = new Mob2();


    //old way of spawning
    // public float mob1SpawnRate = 3;
    // public float mob1Timer = 0;
    // public float mob2SpawnRate = 10;
    // public float mob2Timer = 0;
    
    private Vector2 screenBounds;
    private float spawnNum = 1;

    
    void Start()
    {
        screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //mob spawner
        if(mob1.timer < mob1.spawnRate && playerScr.frogAlive){
          mob1.timer = mob1.timer + Time.deltaTime;
        }
        else if(playerScr.frogAlive){
            spawnMob();
            mob1.timer = 0;
            print("spawn");
        }

    }

    public void spawnMob(){
        if(spawnNum < 2){
            Instantiate(mob1, new Vector3(screenBounds.x * -2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y), 0), transform.rotation);
            spawnNum++;
        }
        else{
            Instantiate(mob1, new Vector3(screenBounds.x * 2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y), 0), transform.rotation);
            spawnNum--;
        }
        
    }

    public void spawnMob2(){
        if(spawnNum < 2){
            Instantiate(mob2, new Vector3(screenBounds.x * -2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y), 0), transform.rotation);
            spawnNum++;
        }
        else{
            Instantiate(mob2, new Vector3(screenBounds.x * 2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y), 0), transform.rotation);
            spawnNum--;
        }
        
    }

}

I would like to move spawnRates into these separate scripts so that I can have unique spawnRates, spawnTimers, and eventually health values for each enemy type.
public class MobScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float spawnRate = 3;
    public float timer = 0;

}


public class Mob2Script : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float spawnRate = 15;
    public float timer = 0;
}

public class Mob1: MobScript
{

}

public class Mob2: Mob2Script
{

}


If someone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated.

"I was no longer able to assign the Mobs" - what exactly does that mean? Your Mob1 and Mob2 classes should inherit the public fields from their ancestors and thus be mutable from outside.

When I try to assign the Mob prefabs in Unity to my mobSpawner script it tells me there's a type mismatch and therefore I cannot spawn anything.

Please post the exact errormessage.

When I run the game I get this:
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
mobSpawner.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/mobSpawner.cs:37)
And when trying to assign the prefabs in Unity it just says Type mismatch in the box I would normally drag my Mob prefabs into.

Ahaaaa ... what's at line 37 in mobSpawner.cs?

ok theres a difference between gameobject and components, all the monobehaviours are   components..    If you have mobscript1  as a variable, and instantiate it, you're trying to make a component, not a gameobject, to add mobscript1 to a gameobejct you'd use addcomponent.

It's the start of this if statement where I'm trying to check the spawnTimer and spawnRate variables from the Mob classes in MobScript.
if(mob1.timer < mob1.spawnRate && playerScr.frogAlive){
mob1.timer = mob1.timer + Time.deltaTime;
}

You need to understand that in Unity, you not only have OOP, you also have the corset of the Unity engine. So, as BugFinder says: it's sometimes not only what you do but also how. So, while your type tree can surely use some improvement, that's not going to be enough. Are you on your own with try&error or are you following some tutorial / course / book ?

Mostly on my own, just taking bits and pieces from different youtube tutorials and stackoverflow threads. Which is how I ended up with such messy un-scalable code.

most of us learn from a combination of tutorials/manuals/sheer stubborness.. however, mess is purely a bad habbit you should try stop yourself from making from the start.. :D bad habbits are hard to break

Yeah next time I will certainly set up the classes from the start and build out from there, rather than trying to fix it all later.

There is no need at all to have those fields in the derived classes ... just have them in the base class and assign different values to them in the Inspector of your prefabs ...

@BugFinder If you have mobscript1 as a variable, and instantiate it, you're trying to make a component, not a gameobject that's not completely true ... if you have a MonoBehaviour as the parameter to Instantiate it will automatically mean that a deep-clone GameObject is created with all the respective components attached  including the one you used as parameter. Plus the return value will be of the same type as the given parameter. What is completely wrong though are these lines public MobScript mob1 = new Mob1(); you NEVER use new on a MonoBehaviour!

@derHugo Ive never used instantiate to make cheat and make a gameobject behind it, that just feels.. weird

@BugFinder that is actually pretty normal whenever you instantiate a prefab and want direct access to a specific component (usually a prefab wide controller e.g. which has references to all contained childs and components) ;)

For what you describe there is no reason to have multiple sub-classes of MobScript at all.
In Unity you assign/adjust the values of exposed fields via the Inspector window/panel!
So having just
public class MobScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float spawnRate = 3;
    public float timer = 0;
}

any class inheriting from MobScript will already also inherit the two exposed (= serialized) fields spawnRate and timer which can then be adjusted in the Inspector. The values 3 and 0 in your code are only the default values but will always be overruled by whatever you put into the Inspector.
Your MobScript2 doesn't really have any purpose that is not already covered by MobScript and further Mob1 and Mob2 seem completely redundant.

Note though that a MonoBehaviour (or in general any Component) can only exist as attached to a GameObject. Using new of them makes no sense and will show as a warning in the console. Again those two fields are supposed to be
public MobScript mob1;
public MobScript mob2;

and will be exposed to the Inspector where you are supposed to assign them.

HOWEVER
It seems that actually this spawn information shouldn't even be sitting on the MobScript at all. It can even be only known to the MobSpawner instead and be a normal non-MonoBehaviour type like e.g.
[Serializable]
private class MobInfo
{
    public float timer { get; set; }
    // These two are a little undocumented hack for exposing read-only auto-properties as fields
    [field: SerializeField] public float spawnRate { get; private set; } = 3f;
    [field: SerializeField] public GameObject prefab { get; private set; }
}

and then whenever you start to write something1, something2 .. rather consider to use a proper collection type like e.g.
[SerializeField] private MobInfo[] mobs;
// or also
//[SerializeField] private List<MobInfo> mobs;

and then do
void Update()
{
    if(!playerScr.frogAlive) return;

    foreach(var mob in mobs)
    {
        mob.timer += Time.deltaTime;
        if(mob.timer >= mob.spawnRate)
        {
            mob.timer -= mob.spawnRate; 
            spawnMob(mob.prefab);
        }
    }
}

void spawnMob(GameObject prefab)
{
    var position = new Vector3(screenBounds.x * 2 * (spawnNum < 2 ? -1 : 1), Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y), 0);
    Instantiate(prefab, position, transform.rotation);
    spawnNum += (spawnNum < 2 ? -1 : 1);
}

